# Is register value corruption a possibility on reentrant functions in ARM C?

Tags: c, arm, reentrancy

Maybe I'm overthinking this since I've been researching for a couple of hours. I have the concept and rules of reentrancy pretty clear now but since I'm doing this for ARM (Cortex-M4), another question came to mind that is not touched on the reentrancy resources I've found, nor in its rules.

I understand that the following function is reentrant from the rules of reentrancy:

```
void foo(int x, int y)
{
    printf("x = %d - y = %d", x, y);
}
```

The thing here is that, at least on ARM where I've verified this, `x` and `y` are passed on registers `r2` and `r3` and not in `foo`'s stack. If they were passed in the stack then there would not be any confusion for me because I know that is preserved across function calls, however, since `x` and `y` are passed in registers, **what would happen if a second call to `foo` is made from another RTOS task context right after the first call has been made?**

```
void foo(int x, int y)
{ <-------------------------------------------- Second call made here
    printf("x = %d - y = %d\n", x, y);
}
```

Wouldn't that corrupt `r2` and `r3` values?

*I haven't been able to test this because I have no idea how to make it happen.*

Comment: In what context, RTOS? A context switch has to preserve relevant registers as well as the stack and sp, or the OS is broken. Interrupts is another story though.

Comment: @Lundin good point!! This is with FreeRTOS so I think I'm safe after all, or am I?. That is a good RTOS. This scenario would not happen on interrupts in my current application so I'm good there.

Comment: If a RTOS corrupted registers during a context switch then any random code using registers would break. This is one of the main reasons why an individual stack is needed per processes (or else where to store register values for later). Interrupts is a lower level concept though, and the only registers stacked are those guaranteed by the ISA - the rest of them would have to be saved manually.

Comment: How can a second call be made on the line { ? There is no function call on the line {

Comment: @user253751 yeah, that was not clear. That could and would happen on an RTOS since there could be a context switch at any time, including that line.

Comment: arm does not define this generically the compiler is responsible for making the code reentrant per the rules of the language.  You violate the language or have a non-compliant compiler, that is bad.  but arm, mips, x86, etc have nothing to do with it.

Comment: THEN you want to add context switching to this, now you are talking about a properly designed operating system vs a not properly designed.  and there are many oses ported to arm and other targets.  This question is massively broad yet easily researched.  what happened when you looked at an rtos and a compiler supported by that rtos or a vendor bundlng it in their sdk and the arm documentation.  All the answers are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever the operating system switches to another thread it has to save all the register values from the old thread and load the register values for the new thread.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. It seems I overlooked this fact. It is as simple as this.